# Maintaining original list order after sorting in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to maintain the list order after sorting. For example, the user enter 2, 4, 7, 1, 0 to be added to the list. How can I maintain this order after using the static sorted method on the list? I tried using a bubble sort method and copy the original list in another list variable, but after passing the list to below sorted method, it sorts the original list even thought it was copied in another list variable.

Is there anyway around this?

```
   private List<int> sortedList(List<int> sortedGrads)
    {


        for (int i = 0; i < sortedGrads.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < sortedGrads.Count - 1 - i; j++)
            {
                if (sortedGrads[j] > sortedGrads[j + 1])
                {
                    int temp = sortedGrads[j];
                    sortedGrads[j] = sortedGrads[j + 1];
                    sortedGrads[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return sortedGrads;
    }
```

Comment: Don't modify the parameter you are taking in. Create a new empty list inside your method. Put your sorted results into the new list and return new list. However you can use the linq Orderby and this is done for you.

Answer (score 2):

To get the sorted list use LINQ and store the result in other variable and keep your original list as it is.

```
private List<int> sortedList(List<int> sortedGrads)
        {
            List<int> sortedElements = sortedGrads.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();

            //use any one from below
            return sortedGrads; //returns the original list
            return sortedElements; //returns the sorted list
        }
```